# JavaFX labels change when clicked

Tags: javafx

I'm new to FXML and am trying to figure out how to get the binary representation of a number to show up on the scene with each bit as an individual label. What I want to happen is when you click on a bit, the number and the label change accordingly (so if the label is a zero, then it will change to 1 and so on). Thanks so much!

Comment: Ask a specific question. Also show attempts of you trying to solve it on your own.

Comment: I don't really know how to start using FXML. I guess a more specific question would be is there a way in FXML to have a for loop (or recognize a method in a java document) that creates an array of labels (or buttons). There need to be about 31 labels (since we're dealing only with positive integers) but how can you reserve the space in the FXML without going through and creating 31 individual labels. That's the part I'm having the most trouble with.

Comment: @user3337808 if you want to get around learning the basics of JavaFX and FXML then an excellent investment would be to read through this tutorial : (http://code.makery.ch/java/javafx-2-tutorial-intro/) . Also regarding your problem of 31 labels one possible solution would be to reserve space for them in you FXML file and then load them from your java controller upon clicking of the say "Show Bits " button . If you need a bit of code for that do let me know